# registerForContextMenu on gridview adapter not called

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);      
    gridview.setAdapter(createAdapter(this));       
    this.registerForContextMenu(gridview);
```

and

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.datacorrection:
            onCorrectData();
            return true;
        case R.id.postfacebook:
            onPostFacebook();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}

protected void onCorrectData()
{

}

protected void onPostFacebook()
{

}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

My custom adapter creates multiple TextViews arranged in the GridView. I want to listen to a long click on each of the TextViews in order to show a context menu. For some reason the onCreateContextMenu is never called even though I called registerForContextMenu on the GridView. I thought through this call all individual views (here: TextViews) will listen to a long click? Pls advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: are you sure your R.id.gridview is unique?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your adapter, call `setLongClickable(true)` on every view you are inflating.